# Curve modifier: Uniform deformation

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

I am following [this simple tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYzBSkqPbTU) on how to create a simple signet ring. The instructions are easy enough to follow, however [at one point](https://youtu.be/nYzBSkqPbTU?t=121) my actions do not reproduce the result displayed in the tutorial.
Instead of that uniform deformation of the cuboid shape along the bezier circle, I get a mixed result indicating that only along half of the circle, the modifier works as intended.
Here is a screenshot for illustration:[image]
Can you point out the source of this difference?

Best,
Clemens

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I should have checked more thoroughly before posting the question: I did not have all of the vertices selected.

Answer (score 0):

I should have checked more thoroughly before posting the question: I did not have all of the vertices selected.
Anyway, maybe this entry will help someone else at some point.

Edit: The problem re-occurred an I have learned that it was not caused by vertex selection. Instead the explanation is:
By default, the Mirror modifier has an option "Merge" activated with a default threshold of 0.001 meters. Because I am working on a thin shape, this caused the phenomenon depicted above.
Solution: deselect the "Merge" option.

Comment: you probably should edit your answer to get straight to the solution and it looks like it starts at *By default, the Mirror modifier has ...*. you can delete everything before that. this will help the reader to get straight to the solution.